# What are common pscp command issues?

Tags: file, batch-file, pscp

I am transferring files from Windows server to Unix server using pscp command.
About 30% files are not getting transferred, I am not getting any specific error in the logs,apart from this:
pscp: MP*.xml: No such file or directory

What can be the possible reason of some files not getting transferred?
What are the common issues with pscp?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

The source files you are trying to copy could be locked for editing. I suggest you close all other applications, restart, and try again.